# reCaptcha onload function from external JS file?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am attempting to implement reCaptcha into my form and then remove the `disabled` state from the submit button once the validation has taken place on the frontend. The problem is that I need to access some variables from an external Javascript file once the reCaptcha has been validated, so I need the load function to be in the external Javascript file. Of course, this won't work, because the load function is out of scope and therefore I get the error `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: loadCaptcha`

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        ....
        <div id="captcha-container"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And here's my Javascript(from an external javascript file):

```
var captchaContainer = null;
var loadCaptcha = function() {
    captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha-container', {
        'sitekey' : 'xxxxxxx',
        'callback' : function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};
```

How can I set this up so that the reCaptcha is rendered on load of the api Javascript file, but do it from within my external Javascript file so that I can access some variables there within the callback of the `loadCaptcha` function?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: You have to load the script. It doesn't do any good if, when you have a script to define a function and a script to call it, you only load the script which calls it. You need to have a `<script>` tag for the other one (and they need to be in the first order).

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could do something like this:

```
window.loadCaptcha = () => {/*do something*/}
```